# Can blender bevel miter be like this?

Tags: modeling

I was doing something like this
[image]

but as you can see the outside corners are are rounded,I thought there is no way fix that,but I until I find this

[image]
this is bevel result from XSI,it allows you to chose miter like this or uniform,and this is some same thing done in XSI[image]perfect
so I wonder is there a way make blender bevel behave like that

Comment: How about: Set Profile Shape to 1.0

Answer (score 1):

Just bevel these parts and you will have sharp angles:

[image]

Test (with a bevel of 2 segments instead of 1):

[image]

Comment: that could be,but my goal is,let's say I got do ten areas of this pattern,I dont want bevel them by hand,want find some ez life

Comment: Yes of course you'll have to do it manually, but once you've done one you can remove some faces, enable Auto Merge and Snap to Vertices, duplicate what you've done